# Passing defined parameters to the Power BI Embeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing, powerbi

It is possible to define the parameters in the Power BI Desktop as per this feature (https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7141377-allow-runtime-parameters-in-power-view-and-or-powe).

Is it possible to send this parameter from the target application (ASP.NET MVC) of the Power BI Embedded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI Embedded does not support parameters yet but you can pass in one additional filter value on the embed URL when you render the IFrame:

`report.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl + "&$filter=table/column eq 'value'";`

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it cannot be accessed through the parameter in the design time. I think the parameter serve the different purpose than the filter, and it perfectly matches to my requirement. Any idea when it will be available?

Comment: What do you mean by design time in this case? Right now parameters are only available on the Power BI Desktop.

Comment: I mean the parameters are defined in the power bi desktop and it is used in the filters in edit queries window by name of the parameter (This is what I assume as design time). Later when you generate the charts you can change values for those parameters (This is what I assume as run time) and can analyze the charts with different parameters. If it is possible to do the same in the power bi embed it would be great.